# Devexpress Find All Controls on the page

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, devexpress

How can I find all DevExpress ASPxWebControls on the page in ASP.NET?

I tried this code:

```
foreach (var item in Page.Controls)
{
    if (item is ASPxWebControl)
    {
        (item as ASPxWebControl).Theme="Metropolis";
    }
}
```

But it's not working.

Comment: Describe "not working". Is your code being reached? Is an exception being thrown? Is it doing part of what you want but not all of it? Be specific and don't assume we know what you mean by a vague "it's not working" statement.

Comment: Hi, sorry for missing information. This code returns only masterpage control. I found the solution. All devexpress controls in Htmlform control. Htmlform control under masterpage controls.

Comment: I Will put code here tomorrow.(my pc not here now) Sorry for english :) have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution

```html
private void changeTheme()//this metod working in MasterPage.
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < Page.Controls[0].Controls.Count; i++)//returns masterpage
            {
                if (Page.Controls[0].Controls[i].GetType().ToString() == "System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm")//find htmlform in masterpage
                {
                    foreach (var item in Page.Controls[0].Controls[i].Controls)//find all controls in htmlform
                    {
                        if (item is ASPxWebControl)//reach all devexpress controls
                            (item as ASPxWebControl).Theme = "Metropolis";//change their theme
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < this.ContentPlaceHolder1.Controls.Count; i++)//find derived page's controls from masterpage
            {
                if (this.ContentPlaceHolder1.Controls[i] is ASPxWebControl)//and reach them
                    (this.ContentPlaceHolder1.Controls[i] as ASPxWebControl).Theme = "Metropolis";
            }
        }
```

this code finds all devexpress controls in masterpage and change their theme.